# Since I have attached mouseover and mouseout event to each and every element in HTML, How can I prevent same event on few HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('body').on('mouseover mouseout', '*:not(.printToolBar)', function (e) {
    if (this === e.target) {
        (e.type === 'mouseover' ? setMenuBox(e.target) : removeMenuBox(e.target));
    }
   });
```

I have tried `.on` and `.off` method also but not able to get desired result.

Comment: I would either use an `if` inside the handler or cease to use delegation. I don't think you can undelegate a handler only for some targets.

Comment: Did the approach below not work out for you?

Comment: @DeepakKaithwas What was it that didn't work? Did you get an error? Did it not work as you expected?

Comment: Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/KNrBC/. Is this something like what you had in mind?

Comment: Here is what I need, I have change the original code, I am setting an List (css absoluted)element using append method so when I hover mouse to any element that element gets wrapped by div and that div contains UL element, but when I hover that UL element it is throwing some error. 'Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy'

Comment: @DeepakKaithwas That is an entirely different problem from the one you have specified in your question. Please edit your question to reflect these requirements

Comment: @Asad answer given by you was correct for that situation, I thought that will solve this one too, apparently I was wrong.

Comment: I was just making a small mistake, as I have excluded the element from binding but forgot to exclude the child element of that, event bubbling was causing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply exclude the undesired elements from your original binding:

```
$('body').on('mouseover mouseout', '*:not(.undesiredelements)', function (e) {
    if (this === e.target) {
        $(e.target).css('border', (e.type === 'mouseover' ? '1px solid blue' : ''));
    }
});
```

"Removing a binding for some elements" is equivalent to changing the selector condition for which the handler is fired. If you need to change the binding after you have already used a loose selector like `*`, you can simply unbind the original handler and rebind to the desired elements.

Note that there is only *one* event handler binding happening here (i.e. to the `body` element)